# How can I specify the opacity of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, opacity

Is there any way to change or specify the browser window opacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't**. The user/browser has total control over what code runs on the client. Unless the browser has its own API for doing this, it's just not possible. None of the common browsers provide such a thing.